# java.lang.NullPointerException when using Java deep-clone library in Eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi everyone I'm developing my own Eclipse plug-in and it has some dependencies on other plug-ins. One other plug-in it needs uses the Java deep-clone library.When I invoke the methods of this plug-in from my own plug-in, a java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$1.compare(AbstractWorkingSetManager.java:97)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:547)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerTreeMap.clone(FastClonerTreeMap.java:22)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(FastClonerArrayList.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashMap.clone(FastClonerHashMap.java:21)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashMap.clone(FastClonerHashMap.java:21)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashSet.clone(FastClonerHashSet.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashMap.clone(FastClonerHashMap.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashSet.clone(FastClonerHashSet.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashMap.clone(FastClonerHashMap.java:21)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashMap.clone(FastClonerHashMap.java:21)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashMap.clone(FastClonerHashMap.java:21)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(FastClonerArrayList.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerHashMap.clone(FastClonerHashMap.java:21)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:462)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(FastClonerArrayList.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(FastClonerArrayList.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(FastClonerArrayList.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(FastClonerArrayList.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(FastClonerArrayList.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(FastClonerArrayList.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(FastClonerArrayList.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.FastClonerArrayList.clone(FastClonerArrayList.java:20)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.fastClone(Cloner.java:108)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:491)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.deepClone(Cloner.java:323)
at generativeGrammar.designAbstractionGraph.impl.FPGAMonitoringImpl.genMonitoringSoCs(FPGAMonitoringImpl.java:181)
at generativeGrammar.designAbstractionGraph.impl.FPGAMonitoringImpl.GenerateMonitoringSoCs(FPGAMonitoringImpl.java:174)
at org.spiritconsortium.xml.schema.spirit.spirit.tests._1GenerativGrammarProject.main(_1GenerativGrammarProject.java:237)
at gripgui.frame.Frame4$2.actionPerformed(Frame4.java:142)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2012)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2335)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:404)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2045)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4649)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2103)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4475)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4633)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4297)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4227)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2089)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2588)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4475)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:96)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:646)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:644)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:108)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:119)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:658)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:108)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:657)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

After this exception is thrown the JVM may also crash.

Later,however,I run the plug-in that my own plug-in depends on as one Java application and nothing abnormal happens.

Does someone have an idea where the problem is?

Sorry for my poor english because english is not my mother tongue

Additional Information:

The version of Eclipse I use is the Indigo version and the version of the Java SDK I use is 1.6

**EDIT:**

I will present some source code here.

I have debugged the code for many times and can ensure that the arguments used by the methods are not empty.

```
    private void genMonitoringSoCs(DesignAbstraction des, List<GenerativRulePair> grs){

    Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
    DesignAbstraction ndes = cloner.deepClone(des);
    List<GenerativRulePair> ngrs = cloner.deepClone(grs);

    DesignGeneration generateDesign = new DesignGeneration();

    for (Iterator<GenerativRulePair> j = grs.iterator(); j.hasNext();) {
        GenerativRulePair gr = (GenerativRulePair) j.next();
        boolean check = this.checkRuleForFPGA(ndes, gr);
        if (check) {
            ndes = generateDesign.GenerateNewDesign(ndes, gr);
            ngrs.remove(0);
        } else {
            DesignAbstraction nndes = cloner.deepClone(des);
            this.genMonitoringSoCs(nndes,ngrs);
        }
    }
    allDes.add(ndes);       
}
```

Comment: Can you ensure that the elements you try to clone are non-null? Did you debugged the problem?

Comment: Add some code or we won't be able to provide answer to your problem.

Comment: Sorry for my late response and I have made some upgrades to my question @lschuetze

Comment: Sorry for the lack of source code and I have made some upgrades to my question @UzorTuTuEjt

Comment: Which lines throw the exception?

Comment: The third line:DesignAbstraction ndes = cloner.deepClone(des) throws the exception @UzorTuTuEjt

Answer (score 0):

First of all do validation of null before this line and check if this case occur during run-time.

Second thing is that I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/issues/detail?id=30) issue which seems quite similar to yours.

> The fast cloners for Sets and Lists should check for a null response from cloner.cloneInternal() before attempting to add to the collection as it's possible that null would be returned due to ignoredInstances or ignored classes.

Comment: But how to explain that there is no exeption thrown when the problematic plug-in runs as a Java application?

Comment: Please describe how are you testing it.

Comment: OK, I have just made a main method in the top-level Class to invoke the above method  as a Java application  @UzorTuTuEjt